# Как определить "мобильность" устройства и удалить класс

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, css-animation

Сайт на `bootstrap 3`. Адаптивность отключена.
Подключена анимация через `wow.js` и `animate.css`

Проблема: На мобильных устройствах анимация тормозит. Её нужно отключить.
С помощью javascript нужно определить, что у нас мобильное устройство и удалить класс. Пробовал так, но не получилось (плохо знаю js)

```
if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet()) {
    // Your code here.
     $(.wow).addClass(".wow-removed").removeClass(".wow"); } else {
    $(".wow-removed").addClass(".wow").removeClass(".wow-removed");
};
```

Comment: Вытащил из ответа: [Определение типа устройства с помощью device.js](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1896)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Можно через медиа-запрос в CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

/*Disable Animation on Mobile Devices*/
.wow {
    /*CSS transitions*/
    -o-transition-property: none !important;
    -moz-transition-property: none !important;
    -ms-transition-property: none !important;
    -webkit-transition-property: none !important;
    transition-property: none !important;
    /*CSS transforms*/
    -o-transform: none !important;
    -moz-transform: none !important;
    -ms-transform: none !important;
    -webkit-transform: none !important;
    transform: none !important;
    /*CSS animations*/
    -webkit-animation: none !important;
    -moz-animation: none !important;
    -o-animation: none !important;
    -ms-animation: none !important;
    animation: none !important;
}
```

}

Comment: Красивое и элегантное решение. Мое уважение и плюс к ответу! =)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте собственные классы бутстрап.

Вот функция, если надо получать это значение часто:

```
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg'];

    $el = $('<div>');
    $el.appendTo($('body'));

    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var env = envs[i];

        $el.addClass('hidden-'+env);
        if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
            $el.remove();
            return env
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть еще такой вариант (правда в IE9< не работает (http://caniuse.com/#search=matchMedia) и необходимо задать крайнюю точку (500px, например)):

```js
if (window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 500px)').matches) {
    // remove class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот мой метод

```
<script>
if(window.screen.width > 800) {
    document.write('<script src="js/wow.min.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css" />');
}

</script>   
<script>new WOW().init()</script>
```